# PHP performance bar is not filling

Tags: php, wordpress

i am trying to make a performance bar too see statistiscs of a wheel. But it is not filling the bar but just putting out the number i did fill in.

Here is the code i am using:

```
<?php 

if( have_rows('details') ): ?>

 <?php   while ( have_rows('details') ) : the_row();?>

<div class="container">
<h2>Performance Chart</h2>
<div class="progress" id="prog1">
<?php $areo = the_field('areo');
      $stiffness = the_field('stiffness');
      $weight = the_field('weight');
      $comfort = the_field('comfort');

?>
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >
    <span>Areo</span>
  </div>
  </div>
<div class="progress" id="prog2">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >
    <span>Stiffness</span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress" id="prog3">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >
    <span>Weight</span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress" id="prog4">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="30"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >
    <span>Comfort</span>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile;

else :

    // no rows found

endif;?> 
<script src="<?php echo THEME_URL?>/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function progress(percent, $element) {
            var progressBarWidth = percent * $element.width() / 100;
            $element.find('div.progress-bar').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500);
        }
        progress(<?php echo $areo ?>, $('#prog1'));
        progress(<?php echo $stiffness ?>, $('#prog2'));
        progress(<?php echo $weight ?>, $('#prog3'));
        progress(<?php echo $comfort ?>, $('#prog4'));
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I am using a Wordpress plugin called Advanced Custom Fields, thats where i get the values from.

Comment: please check console first in your site/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve, but your code seems to work, see the snippet below.

```js
function progress(percent, $element) {
  var progressBarWidth = percent * $element.width() / 100;
  $element.find('div.progress-bar').animate({
    width: progressBarWidth
  }, 500);
}

progress(30, $('#prog4'));
```

```css
div.progress-bar {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress" id="prog4">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="30" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    <span>Comfort</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe you just missed to set a background on the `progress-bar` or must increase the time of the animation.

---

Just looking at the documentation of [`the_field`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/)

> *Displays* the value of the specified field. This function is the same as `echo get_field($field_name);`

So it seems, you don't get the value of the corresponding fields, but show it in your HTML output. To retrieve the field's value, you should rather use [`get_field`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)

> *Returns* the value of the specified field.

So in your case this would be

```
$areo = get_field('areo');
$stiffness = get_field('stiffness');
$weight = get_field('weight');
$comfort = get_field('comfort');
```